# Data not plotting, but no errors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, projection, cartopy

I am trying to plot some precipitation data. The code I'm using is modified slightly from this code [here](https://unidata.github.io/python-gallery/examples/Precipitation_Map.html#sphx-glr-download-examples-precipitation-map-py).

The code works fine when I plot using the data from the site used in the link, but when I use a different dataset I have, it doesn't plot. The biggest difference between this dataset and the dataset used in the link's example, is my dataset is global data. The dataset I am using is also netcdf, is not masked, and I am loading it the same way as the example.

I am familiar with the data and know for a fact I should be seeing something and the contour values used in the example are reasonable for this other set of data I am using.

My code is the same, expect for some changes in the section that plots the figure (below) which I have modified so it will plot a specific area instead of CONUS like in the example (using `ax.set_extent`).

When I do not set the extent it appears to plot the data, but then none of the boundaries (coastlines, state lines, etc.) do not plot. Based on this, I'm guessing it's something with either the dataset itself, something with `set_extent`, or a combination of things that is causing it to go wrong. I am not getting back any kind of errors when I plot it, either way. However, there might be something else I'm missing with it.

In the end, I'm actually comparing my dataset to the dataset used in the example link, so I would like them in the same projection.

Thanks for any insight and let me know if you need more information about the data itself!

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj)

ax.set_extent((x1,x0,y0,y1))

# draw coastlines, state and country boundaries, edge of map.
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES)

cs1 = ax.contourf(ym, xm, data1, clevs, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

# add colorbar.
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs1, orientation='horizontal')
#cbar.set_label(data1.units)

#ax.set_title(prcpvar.long_name + ' for period ending ' + nc.creation_time)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('ncep_model')
```

Results when extent is not included in code above:
[image]

**Edit 1:**

I'll add that I was able to successfully plot the data with this code below (from a default template I made). I tried to change the projection to stereographic, but I was having trouble getting it to plot correctly using basemap because I've never used it before. As an alternative, if you can't figure out the error with the code above and could instead help with changing the projection for the code below, I would also take that. At this point I just want my data to plot correctly in the correct projection I want!

(I also included the results for the code below to confirm that the data should be showing up in this location)

```
LLlat = 40.
LLlon = 263.
URlat = 44.
URlon = 270.

lat = xm
lon = ym

%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(1,figsize=(10, 8),)
plt.title('Convective Precipitation 8/28/2018 0Z (in) Valid July 2018')

map = Basemap(projection='cyl',\
        llcrnrlat=LLlat,urcrnrlat=URlat,\
        llcrnrlon=LLlon,urcrnrlon=URlon,\
        rsphere=6371200.,resolution='i')
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5) # Draw some coastlines
map.drawstates(linewidth=0.5) # Draw some coastlines
map.drawrivers(color='#000000')
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,91.,30),labels=[1,0,0,0]) # Drawing lines of latitude
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,330.,60),labels=[0,0,0,1]) # Drawing lines of longitude
lons,lats = map(lon,lat) # Setting up the grid in cylindrical coords.
cs = plt.contourf(lons,lats,data1[:,:], clevs,cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cb = plt.colorbar(cs,orientation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I've added the resulting plot when I don't include the `set_extent` in the first chunk of code (Don't know if that will help at all, but thought I'd include it as well)

Comment: It's not a solution to your problem. Using plt.show() flushes out the plot from the memory. Your savefig will save nothing. Use plt.show after plt.savefig

Comment: I do know this. I was going to get rid of the plt.show() once I have the problem solved. I guess I forgot to comment it out. haha

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with the basemap plot?

Comment: I want it in a different projection. Specifically, stereographic like in the example. I've been playing with it some more since I've posted and I can't get the data to plot when I'm using basemap either. I'm actually trying to compare my dataset to the data being used in the example, so I want them in the same projection.

Answer (score 1):

So it'd be really useful to have more information on your data, like a link to sample file, but my guess is that your data do not give coordinates in a stereographic projection, unlike the original data. When plotting with Cartopy, if you do not specify otherwise, all plot commands assume that the x,y values given are in the projection specified for the axes (for the original code this was `ccrs.Stereographic`). If this is not the case, such as when plotting lon/lats, you need to specify this by passing `transform` to the plotting command, as below where I specify that the x,y values are lat/lons:

```
data_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
cs1 = ax.contourf(ym, xm, data1, clevs, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
                  transform=data_proj)
```